# Mouse scrolling is not working

Tags: drivers, lxde, mouse-scroll

I have installed Lxde desktop in Ubuntu 12.4, but the mouse scrolling is not working. Can that be a problem with drivers? and when I minimize a window it doesn't show in the task bar, how can I make it visible?

Comment: Did you update and upgrade it? Maybe solved!!...

Comment: Does using two-fingers to scroll work? Check the mouse settings.